# Seboorrheic Dermatitis, Fungi, Environmental Factors

Tags: dermatology, infection, prevention, allergy, hygiene

How can seborrheic dermatitis [not be caused](https://www.aad.org/public/diseases/a-z/seborrheic-dermatitis-overview) by poor hygiene as the assotiation for dermatology said? Wouldn't poor hygiene at least aggravate the condition?

The treatment is mainly antifungal. And the causes are said to be environmental. In winter we stay indoors so as to avoid cold weather, we have poorly oxygenated and poorly ventilated homes because we want to avoid the same cold weather. All these exacerbate fungal infections.

I am not asking why the AAD believes it I am asking why and how it is true. They just happened to assert something that I can't understand and I am questioning its validity. I am not addressing the assertion per se I am addressing the content of the assertion.